# Second Input tag - How can i add?

Tags: javascript

How do I insert Javascript code into the second input?

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="document.getElementById('pass').type = this.checked ? 'text' : 'password'"> Show password
```

*Original code:*

```
document.getElementById('pass').type
```

okey, work but..

```
document.getElementById('pass' 'pass2').type
```

The second "**pass2**" how can I add?

*Sorry for bad English*

Comment: You can't do it like that, you have to execute the same piece of code for the other element. I.e. you have to call `document.getElementById` and do the assignment twice (you can also create a function to encapsulate this logic). It would be easier if you would not use HTML attributes to bind event handlers. Have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html to learn about various ways of binding event handlers.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Look at the part after that... it's part of a conditional operator.

Comment: @Jared: No that seems ok, it seems to toggle clear text/hidden passwords. But I vaguely remember that IE does not let you change the type... not sure though.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yup, IE 8 and earlier don't allow the `type` of `<input>`s to be changed after adding them to the document.

Comment: @minitech - True. Part of why I dislike inline events and ternaries.

Comment: document.getElementById accepts only one argument as string that represents the id of an element on the form. If the element is found, it returns the reference of the object pointing to the element. Which obviously mean that you cannot use it for more than 1 elements.

You can use the reply suggested by @mogelbrod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible, just call `getElementById` twice, preferably with an actual event handler function.

```
function togglePasswordVisibility() {
    if(this.checked) {
        document.getElementById('pass').type  = 'text';
        document.getElementById('pass2').type = 'text';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('pass').type  = 'password';
        document.getElementById('pass2').type = 'password';
    }
}
```

Also, note that your code won't work on Internet Explorer 8 and earlier (I think that's the right version number) because it fixes `type` after the element is added to the document.

Comment: Test: http://jsfiddle.net/AaRUS/ Works in IE9; checking IE8 and below. EDIT: IE8, does not work.

Comment: It also doesn't appear to work using jQuery's `$.prop()` or `$.attr()` in IE8.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Well, jQuery's `prop` and `attr` just delegate to `[]` and `.setAttribute` mostly, so I'm not surprised. Cloning it is messy and breaks event handlers, so I think it's probably best to just leave this feature out on IE8 and earlier.

Comment: I don't think cloning would work either; it would require outputting to markup, replacing, and `$.replaceWith()`. Obviously not a clean approach. Also, does IE8 and below support `onchange` on `input checkbox`?

Comment: @JaredFarrish, Thanks for test! you're wonderful!! But working on jsfiddle.com but does not work on my site.. I find the error in the mysite :) again, thank you!

Comment: @EmreSaracoglu - As an exercise, there is a [*basic method* to support IE8 and below](http://jsfiddle.net/AaRUS/5/) (uses jQuery). Not great, but if you want to support IE8 and below and don't have the issues inherent to the approach (see minitech's comment above), it could work alright. Be sure to test, too.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I'm not sure where you got the markup-replacing idea. This is cloning: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/AaRUS/8/

Comment: I get it from the fact it *doesn't work in IE8 and below*. I guess I assumed you were following me on that logic, but maybe that was my mistake. The only point in doing that was *if* it resolved the IE8 and lower issue. @EmreSaracoglu - Note, a little cleaned up: http://jsfiddle.net/AaRUS/7/

Comment: @JaredFarrish: A salient point :D Markup replacing is still "ew"-inducing (for me), though, so I'd rather do semi-cloning: http://jsfiddle.net/AaRUS/10/

Comment: True, I was thinking of combining the two since @EmreSaracoglu wasn't using jQuery. But you beat me to it. `:)` And at least in the IE9 browser mode, IE7 and 8 both seems to work just fine.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, Works fine now, thank you for your interest and work!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without a loop or copy paste using vanilla DOM functions. I'd either use jQuery or by turning the line into a function which could then be called on change.

jQuery equivalent:

```
$('#toggle-pass').click(function() {
    $('#pass, #pass2').prop('type', this.checked ? 'text' : 'password');
});
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" id="toggle-pass" /> Show password</label>
```